# Ruby 1.9 SVN Bindings in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, svn, binding

I need some help getting the Ruby SVN bindings to work under Ubuntu 12.04

We're using:

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Ubuntu 12.04
- SVN 1.6.17

We are not using rvm.

I tried an `apt-get install libsvn-ruby`, but it doesn't actually seem to install the bindings. When I try to require svn/core, Ruby complains that it does not exist. Looking at a description of the package, it says it's a dummy package.

I have spent quite a lot of time trying to create the bindings manually by checking out http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.6.17 and following the instructions in subversion/bindings/swig/INSTALL, but I always end up getting errors when I try to run `make swig-rb`

None of my Google searches return useful information about the errors, or about how I'm supposed to get the bindings to work. Can anyone give me some steps to get Ruby 1.9 talking to SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there are no ruby bindings for ruby 1.9 - there are only ruby-bindings for ruby 1.8.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 is now supported with svn 1.8 - just build the bindings from the source - `make swig-rb`